# If a CFC is the sole shareholder of a foreign company, is the foreign company itself a CFC

Tags: taxes

More specifically, I'm interested in answering this from the point of view of the US Citizen owning the controlled foreign corporation.  I think the main crux of this question can be restated as "Is a CFC considered to be a US entity?".

Comment: What do you mean by CFC?

Comment: Controlled foreign corporation.